# Bitbake does not include my recipe in build

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to do something straightforward: add a new layer and a new recipe. I used the

> bitbake-layers create-layer

command to create the layer, and added the layer directory path to *BBLAYERS* variable in *BUILDDIR/conf/bblayers.conf*.

**layer.conf**

```
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
        ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"
BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "myname-mytest"
BBFILE_PATTERN_myname-mytest = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_myname-mytest = "6"
LAYERVERSION_myname-mytest = "1"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_myname-mytest = "sumo"
```

Added this in *local.conf*:

**local.conf**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND = " mytest-app"
```

> bitbake-layers show-recipes

shows my layer and recipe.

> mytest-app:
> meta-myname-mytest 1.0

Errors in my recipe are caught in the bitbake build, but without any error, no output is produced under WORKDIR/image or logs are produced under WORKDIR/temp!

Have done this on other platforms, and can't for the life of me tell what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Strangely, inducing any syntax errors in layer.conf and in the recipes outside of any do_* functions is caught, but syntax errors in the do_* functions do not stop bitbake. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`, not `IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND`. c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#appending-and-prepending-override-style-syntax

Answer (score 1):

For the new yocto version, you need to use

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append
```

instead of

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append
```

and you will be OK